# Python loop over files in directory as function argument

Tags: python, io

In my python scirpt I have a function `func01` that takes a pdf file as argument:

```
func01("pdf1.pdf")
```

This works and gives me the expected output.

Now I want to perform `func01` on all files in my directory. I tried this:

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/articles")
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
  myoutput = func01(file)
```

... but this does not work: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Searching on SO, I re-wrote my script to:

```
for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
  path_  = os.path.realpath(file)
  myputput = func01(path_)
```

So what I want is to use each file from the loop as input for my function. What am I missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

implies that somewhere along the line you're doing `"some string"(...)`. In the code you posted you only have a few function calls.

- `os.chdir("/articles")`
- `glob.glob("*.pdf")`
- `myoutput = func01(file)`

So either `os.chdir`, `glob.glob`, or `func01` have been overwritten to be a string.